# Reason to use String instead of Text in Haskell

Tags: haskell, yesod

I hear that good practice in Haskell to use Text instead of String.

I am trying to follow this rule, and coming up with the following question:

Why `parseRoute` of Network-HTTP-Client is designed to work with String and not Text?

What is the general recommendation to use String instead of Text?

https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.2/http-client-0.6.4/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:parseRequest

Comment: The `parseRoute` here takes approximately the size of the URL. Although a URL has no max size, it is strongly adviced to keep URLs shorter than 2048 characters. Together with the method (GET, POST, PATCH, etc.) that will be less than 2100 characters, so I think performance/memory is not very significant here. Note that although in general using Text is indeed better than using strings, due to *list fusion* some string processing algorithms could sometimes be comparable with text processing.

Comment: Thanks! I've got your point. It's a bit strange that I have to unpack my Texts.

Comment: I think it’s also worth noting that String is in general much easier to use than Text, so in a badly designed library, or in one where string processing is not important, String may be preferred over Text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the most likely answer is, sadly, that `String` is still the path of least resistance: the ability to reuse all the familiar list functions (and the very good support for lists in parsing libraries) is so convenient that a largish collection of libraries continue to use `String` despite possible technical advantages of choosing a different type.

Until the cost of the "worse" (but more convenient) choice is carefully quantified and a fix written by somebody who cares, you can expect that to pretty much stay unchanged in any given library.